# How can I get the table name in a SQL Server trigger function?

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

I tried to get the table name in a SQL Server trigger function but I can't.

Please help me.

Comment: Why do you need to do this? You have to name the table when you define the trigger, so you can just use that name.

Comment: The trigger is defined over a definite table, so tablename is well-known in the trigger. IF your triggers over different tables calls the same function then provide tablename value to the function as a parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query for get the table name using trigger function:

```
@tablename = OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) 
                 FROM sys.objects 
                 WHERE sys.objects.name = OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)**
```

Comment: Function calls can be nested.